# Executing a python script from a Node.js script using npm's python-shell is really slow

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, ipc

I'm running a simple Node.js script and within this I am calling an python script using the npm python-shell package. This is all running on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ (Raspbian Buster).

The python script is a hand gesture recognition algorithm for a Raspberry pi and I want to receive a message in the Node.js file as soon as a certain gesture has been detected (The python script I'm executing is found here: https://github.com/MaxLell/Gesberry-Control/blob/master/GesBerry_Pi/GCI_classify.py , I adjusted the code so it doesn't ask for keyboard inputs anymore). The python script includes a `while true:` loop, as it is constantly scanning for gestures. For debugging, I set a print statement in every while loop iteration and it shows that when executing the python script from Node.js, the loop iterations are much slower than if I just execute the python script from the command line. Also, it seems that the iterations become slower and slower the longer I keep the script running from Node.js. The code I am using on the Node.js side is according to the python-shell documentation:

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
let pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {

  console.log(message);
});
```

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?